# Cannot generate razorpay api keys

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

I guess razorpay recently updated their mechanism to generate api keys. Before it automatically showed a modal with the api keys, but now it first asks for website link, after filling it and clicking save I get this

```
{
    "status_code": 400,
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        "bad_request: form locked"
    ]
}
```

Razorpays own docs have Generate Api Keys button but the latest website shows
"Add your Website link
For your account security, we’ll allow payments only on the given links"

Tried looking through docs and videos but all are old. Couldn't find any new ones

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I have been facing the same issue. Just about 2 weeks ago the UI was different. Now they have changed it asking for a website link.

I heard back from Razorpay customer service. For me, they said that my website is not live yet so that is a factor that they oversee before providing the API Keys. Also, the website needs to have a proper 'contact us' page with all contact details along with the different policies like Privacy Policy, Shipping Policy, etc.

Once all this is done, you need to add your website in the Business Settings section of your dashboard. Once all these requirements are met, you will be able to generate the API Key.